# getting always SNAPSHOT version in maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

i have something which is not maven best build choice

this line is from maven:

```
Downloading: http://artifactory.myCompany.com:8080/artifactory/myCompany/org/apache/avro/avro-mapred/1.7.6-cdh5.7.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://artifactory.myCompany.com:8080/artifactory/myCompany/org/apache/avro/avro-mapred/1.7.6-cdh5.7.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 1.8 KB/sec)
```

and i have more lines like that

in my pom.xml file
i have this version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>${avro.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<properties>
    <avro.version>1.7.6</avro.version>
    <jackson.core.version>2.6.4</jackson.core.version>
</properties>
```

i got the version from  [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.avro/avro/1.7.6)

and i have no idea why i am getting the SNAPSHOT version ?
what should i check ?

running mvn dependency:tree

running:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Doutput=c:\company\master\file
```

result this tree:

```
com.myCompany:web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
+- com.myCompany:myCompany-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.4:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.4:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.4:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.6.4:compile
|  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.6:compile
|  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
|  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
|  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
|  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.5:compile
|  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
```

Comment: The artifact you have mentioned `org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.6` is something different than the artifact which is mentioned in the output: `org.apache.org.avro:avro-mapred:1.7.6-cdh5.7.0-SNAPSHOT` which is defined somewhere else in your pom of in a parent pom from which you inherit....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the tree presented wasn't full because someone else from my team added a new project - the top level pom.xml did build all the nested pom.xml file
but the tree i saw wasn't full because of that reason after importing the new project from our repository the full tree was presented and i could see it.

Answer (score -1):

The artifact you have mentioned `org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.6` is something different than the artifact which is mentioned in the output: `org.apache.org.avro:avro-mapred:1.7.6-cdh5.7.0-SNAPSHOT` which is defined somewhere else in your pom of in a parent pom from which you inherit....

Comment: this is the only line in my pom.xml file with avro

Comment: What about a parent pom?

Comment: Have you checked via `mvn dependency:tree` on your project and take a deep look into the resulting tree?

Comment: nothing that i could find - i have added the tree do you see something unusual ?

Comment: Sorry but this is not the whole tree...how could i say something about it?